# JQuery Fluid CSS Floated DIV Rows traversal

Tags: jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

Lets say I have a container div, inside of which are div containers of class 'icon'

e.g.

```
<div class="icons clearfix">
    <div class="icon">...</div>
    <div class="icon">...</div>
    <div class="icon">...</div>
    <div class="icon">...</div>
    <div class="icon">...</div>
    etc...
</div>
```

The width of icons is 100% and sits in a fluid width container. 'icon' containers have a fixed with of 100px (  for purposes of example, though it could be something else).

Given an element representing a div.icon element, how do we determine what position in which row the element is currently in while accounting for browser or container resizing? The first item in the first row? The second item in the fifth row??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that the height of `.icon` classes is fixed then you can determine it like that:

- Determine the position of the div by looking in its `.position()`
- Determine it's row by dividing the `.top` position value with the `.icon` div height.
- traverse backwards (while counting) until you reach a DIV whose `position().left` is 0.
- Drink coffee and relax

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vK3an/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TJNowell/v3kQy/26/ Here's a modified version of my own that's a little more flexible